# Getting this error: "Expression.Error: The column 't_count' of the table wasn't found. Details: t_count" while executing cummulative sum

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Hi I am trying to create a Cummulative sum for "t_count" field in Power BI but everytime I try to run the this formula: `List.Sum(List.Range(#"Added Index"[t_count],0,[Hire_Count]))` I am getting error that `t_count` field was not found in the table. Can anyone help me in creating cummulative sum without getting this error? I am sharing full code from advance editor.

```
   let
        Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\rabi.jaiswal\Desktop\hr_analytics\EMPLOYEE_ATTRITION_DATA.xlsx"), null, true),
        Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
        #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
        #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Emp_Id", Int64.Type}, {"Emp_Name", type text}, {"email", type text}, {"Join_Date", type date}, {"Joined_As", type text}, {"Department", type text}, {"Manger_Name", type text}, {"Current_Designation", type text}, {"Current_Designation_Start_Date", type date}, {"Work Hours", Int64.Type}, {"Standard_Work_Hours", Int64.Type}, {"Term_Date", type date}}),
        #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Emp_Id", "Emp_Name", "email", "Joined_As", "Department", "Manger_Name", "Current_Designation", "Current_Designation_Start_Date", "Work Hours", "Standard_Work_Hours"}),
        #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Columns",{{"Join_Date", Order.Ascending}}),
        #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
        #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Added Index",{{"Index", "Hire_Count"}}),
        #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "t_count", each if [Term_Date] = null then 0 else 1),
        #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Conditional Column", "Term_total", each List.Sum(List.Range(#"Added Index"[t_count],0,[Hire_Count])))
    in
        #"Added Custom"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your index starts with one, so try

```
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Conditional Column", "Term_total", each List.Sum(List.FirstN(#"Added Conditional Column"[t_count],[Index]))),
```

if your index started from zero, it would be

```
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Conditional Column", "Term_total", each List.Sum(List.FirstN(#"Added Conditional Column"[t_count],[Index]+1))),
```